# Online - Create news post from list item in communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've a communication site on my SharePoint Online.

I've created a list on this communication site where I imported items from a previous Announcements List that was in a classic site.

I would like to create a new post with the content coming from the list, so users can see old news/announcements with modern news pages.

Is that possibile? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a **News post**, then in the **post**'s body, embed the announcements in the body.
[image]

[Add content to your page using the Embed web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-content-to-your-page-using-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8)

Comment: Thanks! And do you know if is it possibile to do this with REST API or PowerShell? Because I have to "migrate" about 500 announcements and I would like to do this programmatically.

Comment: No, you have to add them manually.